# Problems with S3 georeferencing using Python-GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, sentinel-snap

I have to work with many Sentinel 2 and 3 images, with two different algorithms. I have to treat both images separately but only with Python and GDAL.

Concerning Sentinel-2 images, I download them on the Scihub, using the L1C-level. I do some corrections and operations on it, and the last step is converting the result into a netCDF file, reprojected in EPSG:4326. To do that, I use GDAL (my first result is in GeoTiff) as follows :

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 inFile.tif outFile.nc
```

I tried to add "-of NetCDF" too, but when I add this, it does not work. Moreover, I have this problem when the output file is in GeoTiff too so I don't think this is where my problem comes from.

On the other side, I work on Sentinel 3 WFR (so downloaded on CODA) images. I only open them in Python, convert them in GeoTiff and crop them on the same Granules as my S2 images. When I try to convert them in GeoTiff via Python, I open the file with the module h5py. I open the file geo_coordinates.nc too, and extract the longitude and latitude on each pixel. Then I match the longitude and latitude to the file (here iop_nn.nc) and I create the GeoTiff with gdal_edit as follows (the file outFile.tif was created before by copying iop_nn.nc array in it) :

```
gdal_edit.py outFile.tif -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_nodata -10000 -gcp pixel1 Line1 lon1 lat1 -gcp pixel2 Line2 lon2 lat2 -gcp pixel3 Line3 lon3 lat3 -gcp pixel4 Line4 lon4 lat4 -gcp pixel5 Line5 lon5 lat5 -gcp pixel6 Line6 lon6 lat6 -gcp pixel7 Line7 lon7 lat7 -gcp pixel8 Line8 lon8 lat8 -gcp pixel9 Line9 lon9 lat9
```

with the gcps taken at corners and centers. Finally, I use gdalwarp. I keep the result before warping and after.

Then I use QGIS to compare the results, and i can  notice a shift between S2 location and S3 location. The shift is about 5-6 S3-pixels (way too much). I found it weird, so I tried to georeference with SNAP and then I had no shift anymore !

I tried to use the file tie_geo_coordinates.nc but it did not work neither, and I can't explain it...

I only got one question : How can I create a weel-georeferenced raster from S3 images using Python and/or GDAL ? (And truly, I don't uderstand why my question is considered as "too broad"...)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please split your question and create a second one.